# Session differences in Pylons and Pyramid

Tags: python, session, sqlalchemy, pylons, pyramid

As a Pylons user I'm trying to switch to Pyramid now trying to understand differences.

In Pylons I was used to define Session in `myproj.model.meta` as:

```
Session = scoped_session(sessionmaker())
```

then import it in `myproj.model` to define model and so on then in app refer to:

```
root = Session.query(MyModel).filter(...)...
```

now using a default template in Pyramid (pyramid_routesalchemy) I define Session as before (except calling it `DBSession` and adding an extension):

```
DBSession = scoped_session(sessionmaker(extension=ZopeTransactionExtension()))
```

but in `views.py` I don't use it directly but instantiate it:

```
dbsession = DBSession()
root = dbsession.query(MyModel).filter(...)...
```

Why? What are the differences?

---

Moreover, what are the differences from Pyramid

```
import transaction
...
model = MyModel(name=u'root', value=55)
session.add(model)
session.flush()
transaction.commit()
```

to Pylons

```
model = MyModel(name=u'root', value=55)
session.add(model)
session.commit()
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Actually the way you are looking up your sqlalchemy session instance for querying doesn't really have anything to do with pylons and/or pyramid.  Pylons may have suggested one of the ways as being the "standard" pylons way but that's it.  The only real difference between the ways you're getting your session is in the example using ZopeTransactionExtension.

ZopeTransactionExtension is a little piece that makes sure every session that opens joins an active transaction.  So if you were to open 5 session's, they will all join the same transaction.  That way if you commit or rollback the transaction, all the work done by the either of the 5 sessions will follow suit.  The transaction module ("transaction.commit()") is key here.

pyramid_tm tries to make setting up a transaction straightforward ... it starts one upon request entry, all scoped database sessions join it... and then at the end of the request, if it discovered an error, it will rollback the transaction.  Otherwise, the transaction will be committed.  That way view-level code never has to create or close/commit/rollback the transaction manually.

Mostly session.flush() is for making sure your database model instances get their primary keys filled in without committing the transaction.

So inside a view all you gotta do is:

```
def myview(request):
    session = DBsession()
    session.add(model)
```

pyramid_tm will make sure session is committed or rolled back appropriately.

Comment: Thanks, very straightforward as you say

Comment: and why now in `paster pshell` I often get `DetachedInstanceError: Parent instance ... not bound to a Session; lazy load operation of attribute 'areas' cannot proceed` accessing relationships while never had this problem in Pylons `paster shell` and how to solve it? Thanks

Comment: +1: Came here trying to figure out how to get the pk value before the end of the request processing, while using autocommit. Calling DBSession.flush() was exactly what I needed to do - thanks!

Comment: Does it make a difference if you use "request.session" in pyramid instead of instantiating a new one ?

Answer (score 0):

For the record, issuing a dbsession.flush() seems to work well for me (it causes the session to commit) and I don't have to deal with any extra imports.

Comment: Sorry but to me `DBSession.flush()` does not issue a commit so, if somehow, I don't call `transaction.commit()` at the end but I just quit pshell all my changes are lost...

Comment: Ah, things are a bit different with pshell. I ran into similar issues with session/db persistence in pshell recently. pshell does *not* use the same codepaths as `serve`; request handling and other internal plumbing is configured differently and requests never really complete or fire in pshell. This may be why you need to explicitly use the transaction manager.

Comment: What seems so strange to me is it's only me complaining about this... How do other pshell users live with this? Mistery... ^^

Comment: @neurino A possible answer to your issue is in the the pshell extensions[0] that you can added via the command-line argument setup or in the configuration file. Also, making it's possible to make your own scripts[1], which can be a handy way of interacting with the data  for routine tasks. 
[0] http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/narr/commandline.html#extending-the-shell 
[1] http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/narr/commandline.html#writing-a-script